# Could these be advantageous additions to an Alien body similar to the human from

Tags: science-based, biology, aliens, mutants

I'm creating an alien race, that is of course, Similar to humans. So far I've created a small list of advantages they have over humans, but there are a few I'm unsure of.

1. A Larger number of muscle fibers.
2. A redesigned rib cage. Rather Series of bars, it's a crisscrossing pattern. With sinewy webbing in between them,
3. Muscle fibers are weaved together for better strength.
4. Iron in their bones for reinforcement.
5. Denser but heavier brain which allows for more functioning parts.
6. Stronger neck muscles
7. Scale hide on their back, legs, and arms.
8. A greater amount of stem cells in the blood.
9. A healing factor that uses Stem cells to rebuild sections of the body.

I'm trying to find if these are biologically possible, and how they can occur.

Comment: Consider asking these one at a time. 1. is meaningless - humans vary a lot. 2. how would it work when breathing? 3. this makes them weaker, I'm afraid. 4. How would it actually work? 5. Why do you think less water would allow for more parts? 6. Don't we have them as strong as we needed? 7. What's the benefit for race that is apex predator by technology?

Comment: Advantageous in what situations?

Comment: These questions would be better adressed separately. One thing to consider is that all adaptions come at a cost so for instance scale hide on their back legs and iron bones won't be good for running speed.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about evolutional adaptations, the result can generally be almost whatever you can imagine that being said there are some logical conclusions nature comes down to.

> 1.A Larger number of muscle fibers.

- sure why not

> 2.A redesigned rib cage. Rather Series of bars, it's a crisscrossing pattern. With sinewy webbing in between them,

- ok.... just realize the advantage of the human ribcage is its lightness and ability to be both flexible and resistant to compressive forces. Making your structure to rigid can make your final form too inflexible.

> 3.Muscle fibers are weaved together for better strength.

- Muscle fibers kind of already are weaved together, depending on your "weave" the end result could be counter productive and less efficient

> 4.Iron in their bones for reinforcement.

- utterly irrelevant. Iron is heavy, solid iron is organically expensive to produce and brittle. Bone is a superior construct because of lightness, flexibility, and organic composition. It can be easily repaired. The thing to remember here is, **sometimes how something is made is more important than what it is made of.**

> 5.Denser but heavier brain which allows for more functioning parts.

- Sure why not, though you just as well say their neuron equivalent is superior to our own allowing smaller lighter brains with the same amount of computing power.

> 6.Stronger neck muscles

- Ok... id only ask why?

> 7.Scale hide on their back, legs, and arms.

- sure why not

> 8.A greater amount of stem cells in the blood.

- ok... stem cells are more a mammalian trait (probably reptiles too ) my point is; You don't need stem cells for improved healing you could just as well say all body cells are able to replace damaged cells.

> 9.A healing factor that uses Stem cells to rebuild sections of the body.

- Stem cells are a healing factor, theoretically they could replace dismembered limbs. The reason they don't is because primarily there aren't enough of them in the human circulatory system. There are other potential factors like telomeric decay.

On the healing aspect another critical factor is metabolism. The bodys ability to process energy which means: capacity of food consumptions, speed to process food into an energy store, distribution of your energy store (nutrients), efficiency of cells ability to use the energy store to achieve their biologic functions.

Comment: I think the point of the stronger neck muscles was to enable the aliens to properly support their denser (and heavier) brains.